# Can't access post in php

Tags: php, forms

Here's my code in a short way. This code can't access post and I don't know why.

```
if ($_POST) {
echo 'post a girdim';
}
?>
<html>
   <head>

   </head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set input `name` like:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" />
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't have any elements in your form with a `name`. Therefore no values are submitted to the server, the `$_POST` array is empty and `if ($_POST)` is `false`.

If you don't want any named elements, you can check whether the request method in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` is `"POST"`.

Answer (score 1):

Give your input tags names.

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
echo 'post a girdim';
}
?>
<html>
   <head>

   </head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should follow this

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
```

and further

you can give name for `input` 
for example

```
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
```

and then you must check this

```
<?php
extract($_POST);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
echo $_POST['submit'];
}
?>
```